# Мяч прилипает к стене

Tags: javascript, функции, время

У меня мяч прилипает к правой и левой стене. Мяч должен быть прикреплен к стене до того момента, пока снова не нажата кнопка старт. После нажатия мяч должен продолжить свой путь в том же направлении, как должен был до прилипания. Не знаю, как так осуществить работу кнопки, чтобы он отлетал

```js
var ballH = {
    posX: 30,
    posY: 30,
    speedX: Math.random() * (20 + 10) - 10,
    speedY: Math.random() * (20 + 10) - 10,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,

    update: function() {
        var ballElem = document.getElementById('IBall');
        ballElem.style.left = this.posX + "px";
        ballElem.style.top = this.posY + "px";
    }
};

var areaH = {
    width: 400,
    height: 300
};

let button = document.getElementById('start');
button.addEventListener('click', start);

function start() {
    setInterval(tick, 40);
}

function tick() {

    ballH.posX += ballH.speedX;
    // вылетел ли мяч правее стены?
    if (ballH.posX + ballH.width > areaH.width) {
        ballH.speedX = 0;
        ballH.speedY = 0;
        ballH.posX = areaH.width - ballH.width / 1.2;
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            ballH.speedX = -ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX = areaH.width - ballH.width;
        });
    }
    // вылетел ли мяч левее стены?
    if (ballH.posX < 0) {
        ballH.speedX = 0;
        ballH.speedY = 0;
        ballH.posX = 0;
    }

    ballH.posY += ballH.speedY;
    // вылетел ли мяч ниже пола?
    if (ballH.posY + ballH.height > areaH.height) {
        ballH.speedY = -ballH.speedY;
        ballH.posY = areaH.height - ballH.height;
    }
    // вылетел ли мяч выше потолка?
    if (ballH.posY < 0) {
        ballH.speedY = -ballH.speedY;
        ballH.posY = 0;
    }

    ballH.update();
}

ballH.update();
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Пуск!' id="start">
<br /><br />
<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px;
    border: solid blue 1px; position: relative'>
    <div  id='IBall'
          style='position: absolute;width:40px;height:40px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас несколько проблем в коде:

```
    ballH.speedX = 0;
    ballH.speedY = 0;
    ballH.posX = areaH.width - ballH.width / 1.2;
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        ballH.speedX = -ballH.speedX; // speedX = 0
        ballH.posX = areaH.width - ballH.width;
    });
```

Скорость мяча будет равна нулю, поэтому добавление минуса ничего не решит

```
if (ballH.posX < 0) {
    ballH.speedX = 0;
    ballH.speedY = 0;
    ballH.posX = 0;
}
```

А почему тут не добавляете обработчик, как в случае с правой стороной?

```
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        ballH.speedX = -ballH.speedX;
        ballH.posX = areaH.width - ballH.width;
    });
```

У нас уже есть функция `start`, можно опять же ее использовать. Для остановки достаточно остановить таймер через `clearInterval`. А еще лучше использовать `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
const ballH = {
    posX: 30,
    posY: 30,
    speedX: Math.random() * (20 + 10) - 10,
    speedY: Math.random() * (20 + 10) - 10,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    ballElem: document.getElementById('IBall'),

    update: function() {
        this.ballElem.style.left = this.posX + "px";
        this.ballElem.style.top = this.posY + "px";
    }
};

const areaH = {
    width: 400,
    height: 300
};

let tickInterval;
const button = document.getElementById('start');
button.addEventListener('click', start);

function start() {
    tick();
    button.disabled = true; // что бы лишний раз не нажимали
}

function tick() {
    let nextTick = true;
    
    ballH.posX += ballH.speedX;
    // вылетел ли мяч правее стены?
    if (ballH.posX + ballH.width >= areaH.width) {
        ballH.posX = areaH.width - ballH.width;
        ballH.speedX = -ballH.speedX;
        nextTick = false;
    }
    // вылетел ли мяч левее стены?
    if (ballH.posX <= 0) {
        ballH.posX = 0;
        ballH.speedX = -ballH.speedX;
        nextTick = false;
    }

    ballH.posY += ballH.speedY;
    // вылетел ли мяч ниже пола?
    if (ballH.posY + ballH.height > areaH.height) {
        ballH.speedY = -ballH.speedY;
        ballH.posY = areaH.height - ballH.height;
    }
    // вылетел ли мяч выше потолка?
    if (ballH.posY < 0) {
        ballH.speedY = -ballH.speedY;
        ballH.posY = 0;
    }

    ballH.update();
    
    if (nextTick) {
      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    } else {
      button.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Пуск!' id="start">
<br /><br />
<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px;
    border: solid blue 1px; position: relative'>
    <div  id='IBall'
          style='position: absolute;width:50px;height:50px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%'>
    </div>
</div>
```